# I need to display checkbox and textbox in single line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display check box and txtMonth in single line.

I use bootstrap 3.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1"><label for="txtMonth">month:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important;">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtMonth" ng-model="month" min="1" max="12" />
            <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 "><label for="txtYear">year:</label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="padding:0!important;margin:0!important;">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtYear" ng-model="year" min="1990" max="2030" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnGetRecords" ng-click="getRecords()" value="ok" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" title="loadfile" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></span> excel
            </button>
            <download-excelto-client month="month" year="year"></download-excelto-client>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The check box in view is alwayes going down under month label.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/52004/).

How can I make checkbox to be in one line with month text box?

Answer (score 2):

if you want arrange input inline use form-inline class of bootstrap

```
 <div class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
           .....................
      </div>
 <div>
```

write the input elements inside this div.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#txtMonth` field is displayed as a block and as such it makes all its following siblings appear at least on the next line. Plus its width is set to take 100% of the available space! So this is the issue that should be addressed.

Since month input field should only show two-digits padded integers `01` to `12` (I guess), it doesn't need to take the whole space. You could make its width vary depending on *Bootstrap* breakpoints values.

The input will be displayed as an inline element (inline-block) and you might have to fix the vertical aligning behavior (this depends on the surrounding context). Given your markup, using `vertical-align: top` seems acceptable.

All the above led me to the following css rules.

```
#txtMonth {
  display: inline-block; max-width: 75%; vertical-align:top; margin-left: 5px;
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 970px) {
  #txtMonth {display: inline-block;max-width: 85%}
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
 #txtMonth {display: inline-block;max-width: 90%}
}

/* You may or may not want the checkbox to appear on the right of the "cell" (available space) */
#txtMonth + input {float: right}
```

There is also a `form-inline` class meant to be used when [forms are implemented in a inline context](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline). But as space shrinks, inputs will be wrapped onto the next line.